# unexpected error in UICollectionViewCell init

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Storyboard to create the controls and received this error on self.lblprice lboutlet when initialization.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.initialize()

}
func initialize(){
    self.lblPrice.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 11)
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.lblBrand.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir-Book", size:15)
    self.lblTitle.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:12)
    self.activityIndicatorView = DGActivityIndicatorView(type: .BallPulse, tintColor: UIColor.themeColor(), size: 20.0)
    self.activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)
    self.imageView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.imageView.center
}
var activityIndicatorView: DGActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet var lblMSRP: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblBrand: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point of initialization the nib hasn't been loaded yet. Put the code into `awakeFromNib()` instead.

**Edit:** Also make sure to call `super.awakeFromNib()` in your `awakeFromNib()` as a best practice.

*Sorry for short answer, I'm answering this from my phone while sitting on the loo. (I hope that doesn't affect the credibility of my answer)*

Comment: I am using Storyboard, not nib